# Download public data directly from FTP to Google Cloud bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ftp

I need to work with some large publicly available large genomic files, and would like to store them on Google Cloud. It makes sense to download them directly, and the most similar thing I can find is to setup a data transfer. Data transfer requires an URL of a TSV file that has links, sizes and MD5.

1. Is there a better way I am not familiar with?
2. How do you even find MD5 for remote objects where it is not provided? Is this even possible?
3. I am not sure why is is necessary to have the TSV at a URL, and not uploaded, but I haven't succeeded in providing one. When I upload the created file to GDrive or TinyUpload and provided the obtained link, the transfer fails with an error like:

Details: First line in URL list must be TsvHttpData-1.0 but it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of gsutil command from GCloud SDK in order to copy from and to Google cloud storage.

gsutil cp {SOURCE} {DESTINATION}
In this case, destination will be like : gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{FOLDER_NAME}

Comment: can this source be a FTP?